# What does the metadata tell you about an image and its sensor?

Tags: metadata, erdas-imagine, sensormodel

I'm using a software called ERDAS and my tutor says that the Metadata can be used to detect which sensor your image came from. Is there anything you can tell me that links the metadata to the sensor?

If you're wondering what the metadata of my image says:

```
Projection Info:
Projection: UTM Zone 30 (I'm assuming this is some kind of global geographical database?)
Projection Type: UTM
Spheroid: WGS 84
Datum: WGS 84
Datum Parameters: 0.0
EPSG Code: 32630
Projection Detail: Transverse Mercator
```

I'm supposed to play detective with this part of the assignment.

Comment: Wrong metadata, but it's your assignment, and you need to start detecting.

Comment: Hi Peter - Maybe have a look here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Hi Vince, if that's the wrong metadata, where do I look?

Comment: Just to let you know that I've got the answer. I won't say it here.